# Is DRM supported in HTML5 audio/video?

Tags: html5-video

Does HTML5 audio/video support OMA DRM or any third party DRM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [it doesn't](http://gizmodo.com/5538264/hulu-says-html5-isnt-ready-yet).

At least, not yet. But given the trouble we're having getting browser manufacturers to even agree on a standard *format* I can only imagine how hard it would be to get them all to support a standard DRM (or even to support it at all!)

Comment: I'll bet that DRM will be in there long before decent hardware acceleration of HTML5 Video :P Seeing that Firefox and Chrome both eat like 70% of my CPU with a 480xWhatever Video, while VLC not even needs 10% in for HD, makes me mad each time...

Comment: is there any other way to achieve DRM/third party protection for video tag in html5 through Javascript?

Comment: @sri Not at the moment. The whole point of HTML5 video is to promote a standards-based open web. Of course, all the content providers are looking to sneak DRM into the HTML5 video standard.

Comment: This is a solved problem now I think and the accepted answer should probably be changed...

Answer (score 6):

It does now.
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html

Here is an example.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

This is the best page that I could find on current browser support.
http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/

At the time of writing this, EME is supported in

- IE11 in Win8.1
- Chrome (Desktop and mobile)
- Safari 8 in OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about what it is that you're trying to do.

HTML5 sends information over the HTTP protocol.  This includes embedded flash videos, HTML5 {video} tags (if ever finished!), pictures, lyrics, text, links, and javascript.

All of these components are always transmitted in plaintext.  If HTML5 were to include any form of protection on these elements (i.e. tags that indicate that you can't copy?... {drm}{/drm}, etc), it is still up to any software interpreting this HTTP data, to decide whether or not to enforce it.

You can look at a video tag such as youtube or dailymotion - the source it references is always accessible at a standard HTTP address - with or without DRM, the means of downloading this video are within everybody's reach!

This implies that the protocol, by design, does not allow for copy-protection.

For future reference, ask yourself "Is the data (and how it is operated upon) ever in the customer's hands?".  If the answer is 'yes', DRM does not make sense to apply.

Comment: Delivering the content over HTTP doesn't prevent encryption. Currently, it's done using plugins (Flash, Silverlight), it could be done without, if the browser vendors implement the protection themselves.

Comment: Flash allows you to download DRMed content over HTTP - for example the BBC and Channel4 in the UK provide "watch again" services which make use of this technology. The DRM is to protect the file to video/audio frames transition, not the website to customer transition that HTTP manages.

Comment: not to mention that DRM is 90% easy to get around or remove. You can download streamed content with a program that intercepts those streams. Even "rentable" audio files can be un-DRMed by recording it while playing.