# How can I prevent access to assets files(mp3) route

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

(Sorry for my English)
Hello, I have a list of audios where there are two kind of privileges [play] and [play and download].

So, Im using something like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload">
   <source src="/files/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

When the user can [play and download] I only remove `controlsList="nodownload"`

My problem is that an user that only have the privilege to play audios can open the source code + search`.mp3` and have access to my audio url, e.g. `/files/test.mp3`, add the host and have access to the mp3 file and download it.

Im using ASP.NET so e.g. `host/files/`  is Inaccessible but `host/files/test.mp3` is accessible.

I'd like to block the access to all the routes that finish in .mp3 or I don't know any other recommendation?

Comment: If you blocked all routes that ended in .mp3, wouldn't that block the audio from being played? Also, it's fairly simple for users to remove `controlsList="nodownload"` themselves using devtools.

Comment: yes, you're right!... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You're probably looking for "DRM". Here are a couple links: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137888/5764553 and https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that EME is what I need. (Y)

Comment: Another option is not to expose the files directly through the webserver, but instead point your audio element at an action method which first checks the user's permissions before deciding whether to return the file (which is held in a folder not directly accessible via a URL).